# An unexpected error occurred: Error: Cannot find module '@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox'

Tags: solidity, hardhat, framework

When I use the command `npx hardhat` after successfully creating project via npm and installed hardhat I get such an error
An unexpected error occurred:
Error: Cannot find module '@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox'

[image]

One of the best way to fix such a problem is to use "Starter kit" by chainlink. Here is a link: https://github.com/smartcontractkit/hardhat-starter-kit
It's a good way to create your project

But I still want to figure out how to solve this problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After initializing the hardhat project you need to install the toolbox too.
With this command

```
npm install @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox
```

Comment: This is the first thing I tried when solving the problem, but it still doesn't work

Comment: I just noticed this.
Are you trying this inside an npm project? that is already initiated? 
Please try `npx hardhat` in an empty folder. It doesn't initiate inside any folder that is not empty