# Error: Cannot find module '@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox' when setting up hardhat

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I wanted to setup a simple hardhat project so I followed the instructions on the website to create a simple project: `npm init -y` after that `npm i --save-dev hardhat` and to finish `npx hardhat` but when i run `npx hardhat` this error comes up:

> An unexpected error occurred:
>
> Error: Cannot find module '@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox'

I tried installing `@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox` but it still didn't work. Can someone help me?[image]

**hardhat.config.js**

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.17",
};
```

Comment: You can easily avoid this type of issues by starting from a predefined Hardhat boilerplate, e.g. https://github.com/gabrielstoica/hardhat-boilerplate

Comment: Thank you very much, i couldnt fix the bug but this helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

try running any other hardhat command, for example npx hardhat compile, if it does work, it means you're just using the command unproperly, since you have to pass an option after hardhat.

If this does not work, try erasing your node modeles directory and repeat the intalation of hardhat process.

If still this do not work, again delete node_modules, and run "yarn"

I hope it helps

Comment: I tried everything you told me to do but it still didn't worked

Comment: Strange, maybe you can try: npm install --save-dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox and if this does not work, again delete node_modules, and do yarn add --save-dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox. If you need more help after this, try sending a print screen for further help

Comment: still didn't work, i added the picture of the error message, do you think that it could be a hardhat bug?

Comment: This is uncommon, do you have hardhat globally installed? Anyway try to delete using this command "rm -rf node_modules/" (caution with this command, it deletes recursivly, which means you can end up braking stuff, caution when using it) inside you hardhat project folder. and redo the steps I mentioned before. If yet again this is not working, pls share your hardhat.config (caution, don't share private key!!!!)

Comment: Im kinda desperate now, i tried it but it still didn't work. This is my hardhat.config file as you requested 

`require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.17",
};`. I also added it to the question

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you init a hardhat project in an empty folder.

Another thing is to install toolbox via this command:

```
npm install --save-dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox
```

If these two things are correct I don't think there should be any problem.
Also there is a similar question to this [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/149667/an-unexpected-error-occurred-error-cannot-find-module-nomicfoundation-hardha/149673?noredirect=1#comment167841_149673)